# Gitlab Django CI/CD postgres: Connection refused

Tags: django, postgresql, gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

## The Error

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my Django CI/CD working.
I am using Django + postgres, my test cases all pass but I want to implement continuous integration.
Note the the following output is **from the Gitlab Runner**.

I keep getting this error: (the `...` is where I've left out some detail, but its just traceback or name specific stuff about my project etc.)

```
$ cd src
$ python manage.py makemigrations
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:105: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
  warnings.warn(
Migrations for 'app':
  app/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model ...
...
...
$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

## Config files

### `.gitlab-cl.yml`

```yaml
image: python:latest

services:
  - postgres:latest
variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

cache:
  paths:
    - ~/.cache/pip/

before_script:
  - python -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
  script:
    - python manage.py makemigrations
    - python manage.py migrate
    - python manage.py test --settings mysite.cicd_settings
```

### `settings.py`

As you can see, I have specified a different settings file `cicd_settings` to run my tests:

```py
from mysite.settings import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432',
   },
}
```

It inherits everything from my normal `settings.py` file, but overrides the database settings.

## Tried Solutions

I have tried the following solutions:

Postgres Gitlab tutorial:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html

Similar Stackoverflow question:
[GitLab CI Django and Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897360/gitlab-ci-django-and-postgres)

Using `dj_database_url` package:
[Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) - PostgreSQL on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779524/could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-0x0000274d-10061-postgresql)

Default setup for Django Gitlab CI/CD
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Django.gitlab-ci.yml

As you can see, I am using a very simple setup for the tests, but I still can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script fails at the `python manage.py makemigrations` line, since you don't specify the `--settings` for it. But actually, you don't even need to run migrations manually for tests - it will be automatically done by the test runner, to the test database.

So remove both `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` from the test block and it should run successfully.

Moreover, you would never want to run `makemigrations` automatically. It's a tool to be used in development, and the resulting migration are to be included in the VCS (git).

Comment: removing the 2 migration lines does break, but adding the `--setting` part to them does fix, so I suggest that you edit your answer to reflect this. I have submitted a guide to the Community Wiki here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68243461/django-postgres-ci-cd-testing-guide

Comment: That sounds wrong. How exactly does it fail without that lines? Again, you should **never** have `makemigrations` in your CI code. You **only** run it manually on your local machine to produce migration files and commit them to VCS.

Comment: I've made a pastebin link for the output along with the exact yml file: https://pastebin.com/754htAB1

Comment: Did you include **ALL** migrations files in your repository after running `makemigrations` locally? It looks like they are not there, hence the error

Comment: I don't follow? I don't commit the contents of my `migrations/` folder (other than `__init__.py`). Isn't it bad practice to commit migrations? Especially during development where the database is often empty and definitely during testing where an empty database is initialized.

Comment: No, you must commit migrations to the git. Check out the first page of the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/ or this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035119/should-i-be-adding-the-django-migration-files-in-the-gitignore-file